# Sequencer's Reverb for Pro Tools

Tags: reverb

Just wondering if you guys know any reverb that does sequencing for Pro Tools. I'm looking something exactly like Logic's Space Design.

Here's an interesting article:
http://getthatprosound.com/the-10-best-reverb-plugins-in-the-world/

Comment: Actually i don't quite understand what you are looking for.....Are you looking for a reverb that's capable of loading IRs? Or do you want to know if there is reverb that's coming with Pro Tools?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "reverb that does sequencing for Pro Tools". Any of the commercial plug-ins on the list you supplied will work with Pro Tools.